# Is it possible to query multiple lists using CSOM in a SharePoint site?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

My specific issue is that I am given URLs in the following format:

https://sharepoint.business.com/sites/SHAREPOINT/_layouts/15/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=SHAREPOINT-823645913-12

There is no way to directly retrieve document data using that type of link, without first converting it to a server absolute file path, for example:

https://sharepoint.business.com/sites/SHAREPOINT/Documents/TestDocument.pdf

From the given URL, I have no indication of which List I will find the actual document in, so currently my only solution is to query ALL lists in a loop, which seems really bad and inefficient.

Is there a simple/elegant way to query all data within the entire SharePoint site, using the unique Document ID?

Current pseudo-code:

```
ListCollection lists = SharePoint.Client.Web.Lists;

ctx.Load(lists);

ctx.ExecuteQuery();

Loop at all lists {
    Use CAML query to grab absolute file path from Document ID.
}

Retrieve individual file that I actually want, using GetFileByServerRelativeUrl API method.
```

Thanks in advance, and let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using Search API to search across the entire web or site collection.

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query;

string documentId = "SHAREPOINT-823645913-12";
KeywordQuery kQry = new KeywordQuery(clientContext);
kQry.QueryText = "DocId:" + documentId;
SearchExecutor searchExec = new SearchExecutor(clientContext);
ClientReuslt<ResultTableCollection> results = searchExec.ExecuteQuery(kQry);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

foreach(var result in results.Value[0].ResultRows)
{
    //do stuff with result which contains the URL property for the document
    //along with any other crawled attribtues
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Maarten, this does work. However, it's worth noting that I had to change which authentication I was using (in my specific scenario) in order for the server not to reject any Search API requests.

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad it worked :) Even if you had to tweak it a bit for your specific authentication requirements